# Selenium Web Driver - Not able to switch to Iframe using dynamic iframe id

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jxl

I am trying to switch to iframe with dynamic iframe id. However, error out as below. Any help will be appreciate.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id iframe-8c590576-9047-4baf-a34f-69fe67a295a1
```

Following are my HTML out of following first iframe that I want to switch:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" class="iframe-4be2b789-7f13-4350-9771-0523258c080e contentPanelFrame" data-content-url="en_US/Person_homePagePDCPage.do?o3ctx=4096&amp;concernRoleID=-8841741561699565568&amp;evidenceType=null" data-dojo-attach-point="frame" frameborder="0" id="iframe-4be2b789-7f13-4350-9771-0523258c080e" iscpiframe="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="Content Panel - Home" src="en_US/Person_homePagePDCPage.do?o3ctx=4096&amp;concernRoleID=-8841741561699565568&amp;evidenceType=null">&nbsp;</iframe>




<iframe allowtransparency="true" class="iframe-8e82cd97-893d-41ec-b2e5-c6151d6a34a6 contentPanelFrame" data-content-url="en_US/SCSysMAAdminHomePagePage.do?o3ctx=4096" data-dojo-attach-point="frame" frameborder="0" id="iframe-8e82cd97-893d-41ec-b2e5-c6151d6a34a6" iscpiframe="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="Content Panel - Home" src="en_US/SCSysMAAdminHomePagePage.do?o3ctx=4096" cd_frame_id_="146a47c04d9f04d598ccfa3f99c1674d">&nbsp;</iframe>



<iframe allowtransparency="true" class="iframe-f41ba74a-5362-41f5-977f-e144c8c7e4e2 contentPanelFrame" data-content-url="en_US/Person_search1Page.do?o3ctx=4096" data-dojo-attach-point="frame" frameborder="0" id="iframe-f41ba74a-5362-41f5-977f-e144c8c7e4e2" iscpiframe="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="Content Panel - Home" src="en_US/Person_search1Page.do?o3ctx=4096">&nbsp;</iframe>



<iframe allowtransparency="true" border="0" class="detailsPanelFrame iframe-ef98a903-a64e-4b67-bba1-46a86eb2569c" data-content-url="en_US/Person_homeTabDetailsPage.do?concernRoleID=-8841741561699565568&amp;o3ctx=36864" frameborder="0" height="99%" page-id="Person_homeTabDetails" scrolling="no" width="99%" src="en_US/Person_homeTabDetailsPage.do?concernRoleID=-8841741561699565568&amp;o3ctx=36864" title="Context Panel - Sharone Stone"> </iframe>



<iframe _srccontents="en_US/Participant_resolveParticipantSmartPanelPage.do?concernRoleID=-8841741561699565568&amp;o3ctx=266240" allowtransparency="true" border="0" class="smartPanelFrame iframe-f9201550-6ac4-4916-9262-988c17c9a24d" frameborder="0" height="99%" id="curam_tab_SmartPanelIframe" iframeloaded="false" name="curam_tab_SmartPanelIframe" page-id="Participant_resolveParticipantSmartPanel" scrolling="no" src="" title="Smart Panel" width="99%"> </iframe>



<iframe allowtransparency="true" class="iframe-7c91f6ef-a3d3-460e-83b5-d405503921e3 contentPanelFrame" data-content-url="en_US/Activity_redirectCurrentUserCalendarPage.do?o3ctx=4096&amp;startDate=null&amp;calendarViewType=null" data-dojo-attach-point="frame" frameborder="0" id="iframe-7c91f6ef-a3d3-460e-83b5-d405503921e3" iscpiframe="true" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" title="Content Panel - Home" src="en_US/Activity_redirectCurrentUserCalendarPage.do?o3ctx=4096&amp;startDate=null&amp;calendarViewType=null">&nbsp;</iframe>



<iframe id="ie-progress-indicator-helper" name="null" src="about:blank" onload="null" style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px; height: 1px; width: 1px; visibility: hidden" title="ie-progress-indicator-helper"></iframe>



<iframe id="ie-progress-indicator-helper" name="null" src="about:blank" onload="null" style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px; height: 1px; width: 1px; visibility: hidden" title="ie-progress-indicator-helper"></iframe>



<iframe id="ie-progress-indicator-helper" name="null" src="about:blank" onload="null" style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px; height: 1px; width: 1px; visibility: hidden" title="ie-progress-indicator-helper"></iframe>
```

Following are my code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-8c590576-9047-4baf-a34f-69fe67a295a1");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
```

I tried using the xpath as below however no luck:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/iframe/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/[contains(@class, 'field-link') and contains(@class ,'external-link')]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: There is no `<iframe>` in the html

Comment: hi Guy - I updated iframe id in the HTML.

Comment: Is there only single iframe or multiple iframe like this on the page??

Comment: hi Saurabh Gaur - I saw HTML and I found multiple iframe id there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the `iframe` as web element using partial id or class and use it to switch.

It looks like the `src` attribute is unique. You can use it to locate the frame.

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[src*='en_US/Person_homePagePDCPag']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

Comment: hi Guy - I found multiple iframe with dynamic id on the page where I want to switch to particular iframe So in this case the object we created it might look for another iframe ?

Comment: @Curious Can you post the other frame html? The idea is to identify the target frame, any unique selector will do.

Comment: Hi Guy - I updated all iframe HTML above and out of that first iframe I want to switch.

Comment: Hi Guy - I updated my code as you suggested and it worked for me this time to switch the iframe that I wanted to. Thank You very Much!!

Answer (score 0):

it is a bad practice to select context (iframe) by ordering, but if there is no other way to identity them you can use the following example.

```
public void fillStripeTextInputWithNameAndValue(String name,String value) 


throws Exception{

           switch (name) {
               case "cardnumber":

                   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='__privateStripeFrame4']")).sendKeys(value);
                   break;


               case "exp-date":
                   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='__privateStripeFrame5']")).sendKeys(value);
                  break;


               case "cvc":
                   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='__privateStripeFrame6']")).sendKeys(value);
                   break;


                   default:
                       throw  new Exception("Unknown stripe input field");
           }
       }
```